# i want to replace character "a" with character "z" using recursion only

Tags: c++, function, recursion, definition, c-strings

I am beginner in programming i want to print this array as letter "a" should replace the letter "z" and print the updated string

```
#include <iostream>
    char strng(char[],int);
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
        char s[]="all in all";
        int i=0;
        char result;
        //cout<< sizeof(s);
       result=strng(s,i);
       cout<<result;
        return 0;
    }
    char strng (char name[],int i) {
        if(!name){
            return (0) ;
        }
        else if(name[i]=='a'){
            name[i]='z';
            return (strng(name ,i++));
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the question, please?

Comment: On completion the function returns the single `char` value `0` which you then output.

Comment: you need the recursive call outside the inner `if`

Comment: The end detection should be `if(!name[i])` or `if(name[i] == 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function implementation is too complicated and invalid.

For example in this statement

```
   if(!name){
        return (0) ;
```

there is a check whether `name` is equal to nullptr while you need to check whether name[i] is equal to the null-terminating character `'\0'`.

```
   if(!name[i]){
        return (0) ;.
```

Due to the post-increment operator used in the return statement

```
return (strng(name ,i++));
```

the function calls itself with same value of `i` before incrementing.

And the function shall return pointer to the modified string that is its return type should be `char *`.

The function can bedefined the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

char * replace_char( char *s, char source = 'a', char substitution = 'e' )
{
    if ( *s )
    {
        if ( *s == source ) *s = substitution;
        replace_char( s + 1, source, substitution );
    }       

    return s;
}

int main() 
{
    char s[]="all in all";  

    std::cout << s << '\n';
    std::cout << replace_char( s ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
all in all
ell in ell
```

Comment: Hi @VladfromMoscow, I guess using `std::cout<<str<<endl;` makes sense instead of using `\n`.

Comment: @MandarA There is no greate difference.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

void replaceChar(char *ptr, int len){
  if(len == 0 ){
    if( (*(ptr+len)) == 'a' ){
      (*(ptr+len)) = 'z';
    }
  }
  else{
    if((*(ptr+len)) == 'a'){
      (*(ptr+len)) = 'z';
    }
    replaceChar(ptr, len-1);
  }
}


int main() {
  char str[] = "Mandar";
  puts(str);
  replaceChar(str,strlen(str) - 1);
  puts(str);
}
```